# Why won't my phone update to Lolli, and can I force it to?

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop, moto-x

I was totally looking forward for the update but nothing happened, even when I went to look for updates. Weird. It's a Moto X 2nd generation, with Verizon as my provider and hasn't been rooted. I have no idea why it wouldn't update, I tried looking it up but couldn't find any definite answers.
At one point since the release I have had to reset my phone, and the update still hasn't happened, so I'm sure that anything that could've been blocking it should be gone, if that's a possibility.

I have thought about rooting it, but not only am I unsure of how, I don't know how to tell if my phone'll get bricked.

Comment: Updates roll out in waves. Just bide your time, and your turn will come (provided there is an update for your phone).

Comment: No, see, I already knew it wasn't going to happen on its own. I'm asking how I can do it on my own without autoupdate. Not the same.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would suggest ring up your carrier, which in your case would be verizon. I had a similar problem a year or so ago with the Kit Kat update and my carrier pushed the update through. It's worth a try.

Also, if you're planning on rooting your device i would wait till after you have 5.0 Lollipop as many people can not get the update due to having certain root files stopping the phone from reciving it. On top of that there is no telling whether or not your device will get bricked but 95% of the time there are never any problems with rooting your device aslong as you follow all the appropiate steps. There are multiple step by step guides on the internet to follow aswell as videos. Read up about how to do it and watch a few video's before trying it so you get used to all the steps. Once you have rooted it is really worth it.

Coming back to getting 5.0, have you thought about side loading the update on to your phone?